ACL2 and modular arithmetic
I'm trying to prove Motrellin's lemma in ACL2.
$$ \forall m, n \in \mathbb{N} \mathop. 2m = 3n \to 2 \mid n $$
I recently completed a very long-winded Coq proof of it and I'm trying to figure out how one would prove it in ACL2.
ACL2 has a primitive mod that can be used to do modular arithmetic.
ACL2 !>(mod 7 4)
3

Also, mercifully, mod is restricted to rational arguments in ACL2.
ACL2 !>(mod #C(0 1) 2)


ACL2 Error [Evaluation] in TOP-LEVEL:  The guard for the function call
(MOD X Y), which is 
(AND (REAL/RATIONALP X) (REAL/RATIONALP Y) (NOT (EQL Y 0))), is violated
by the arguments in the call (MOD #C(0 1) 2).
See :DOC set-guard-checking for information about suppressing this
check with (set-guard-checking :none), as recommended for new users.
To debug see :DOC print-gv, see :DOC trace, and see :DOC wet.

However, I am having issues proving extremely basic facts about modular arithmetic in ACL2.
ACL2 will accept the following definition
(defun cong (x y n)
  (= (mod x n) (mod y n)))

And it appears to work.
ACL2 !>(cong 0 77 11)
T
ACL2 !>(cong 1 4 8)
NIL

However, it rejects the following theorem.
;; REJECTED
(defthm three-times-mod-2
        (cong (* 3 (nfix x)) (nfix x) 2))

I also tried just checking if the difference is zero mod $n$ to see if I would have better luck.
ACL2 !>(defun cong0 (x y n) (zerop (mod (- x y) n)))

And ACL2 again rejects this theorem.
;; REJECTED
(defthm three-times-mod-2
        (cong0 (* 3 (nfix x)) (nfix x) 2))

I know that, at a core level, ACL2 has some facts about its primitives that are automatically enabled and these can be used to build further facts.
However, I'm really struggling to come up with modular arithmetic facts that are simple enough to get the ball rolling. The following theorem is also rejected.
;; REJECTED
(defthm sum-of-two-numbers-is-even
        (cong0 (+ (nfix x) (nfix x)) 0 2))

So, my question is twofold:

How would one work one's way to up to any of the rejected theorems in this question?
What does ACL2 know about mod without user-defined facts?


I'm curious.  What is the reason this is so hard to prove?

Take the equation modulo 2, you get $0 = 1n = n \mod 2$.  So $2\mid n$.    So my question is what is the reason this is so hard to define lemmas for in ACL2?

You can prove this as follows:
(include-book "arithmetic-5/top" :dir :system)


(defthm lem1
    (implies (and (integerp N)
                  (rationalp R)
                  (integerp (* (+ R 1) N)))
             (integerp (* R N))))
    

(defun divides (x y)
  (AND (ACL2-NUMBERP X)
                   (NOT (EQUAL X 0))
                   (ACL2-NUMBERP Y)
                   (INTEGERP (* Y (/ X)))))

(defthm motrellin-lem
    (implies (and (equal (* 2 m) (* 3 n))
                  (integerp n)
                  (integerp m))
             (divides 2 n)))

ACL2 has a number of number theory libraries, including, but not limited to the following

arithmetic-5 (also arithmetic)
projects/numbers
kestrel/number-theory
kestrel/arithmetic-light

There's generally a surprising amount of gems in the community libraries, but you really have to look for them.
On a side note,

Also, mercifully, mod is restricted to rational arguments in ACL2.

Don't be fooled by this, guards only serve the purpose of optimizing execution, they don't actually provide any logical guarantees. So even if a function has guard (rationalp X), the guard will be ignored in a proof involving the function. The usual way around this is to define
(defun foo (x)
  (declare (xargs :guard (rationalp x)))
  (if (mbt (rationalp x))
    ...
    nil))

This has the effect that (mbt P) evaluates to P logically, but evaluates to 't when executed.
